# Loop through elements beautifulsoup

Tags: python, selenium, beautifulsoup

I'm not sure what the problem is. But I have a small script using Selenium and Beautifulsoup 4 to visit and parse contents of a specific website using specific inputs. For each search word I want to append the elements to lists. This is the html:

```
<table class="aClass">
       <tr class="1">
        <td>
         <a href="aLink">
          <span class="aClass">
           Text
          </span>
         </a>
        </td>
        <td>
        </td>
        <td>
        </td>
        <td>
        </td>
       </tr>
       <tr class="2">
        <td>
        </td>
        <td anAttribute="aValue">
         Text
        </td>
        <td>
        </td>
       </tr>
</table>
```

The wanted td is in 2nd tr and the span is in the one just before it. The pattern continues for X amount of hits, inside the table-element.

The expected outcome is 238 in each list, but when I print the length it doesn't even come close. It stops at 25. When I write the data to a file the same problem exists. Yet the list does contain results from all the different searches. I thought the way I targeted the elements might be the problem, but comparing to the structure of the html this doesn't seem to be the case. Am looping through the elements in the wrong way?

Complete code:

```
def searchAndExtract():
    searches = ['Search1', 'Search2', 'Search3']
    textContents = []
    idContents = []
    data = []
    data.append(['ID', 'MESSAGE'])
    driver = webdriver.PhantomJS()
    url = 'https://website.com'
    driver.get(url)
    for search in searches:
        input = driver.find_element_by_id("q")
        element = input.get_attribute('value')
        if len(element) > 0:
            input.clear()
        input.send_keys(search)
        input.submit()
        pagehtml = driver.page_source
        soup = BeautifulSoup(pagehtml)
        identifiers = soup.find_all('span', {"class": "aClass"})     
        messages = soup.find_all('td', {"anAttribute": "aValue" })
        for identifier in identifiers:
            idContents.append(identifier.text)
        for message in messages:
            textContents.append(message.text)
    for i, ids in enumerate(idContents):
        data.append([ids, textContents[i]])
```

So I'm looping everything the wrong way, I still think. But I dunno what exactly I should be doing. I tried this, but continue only to get the first 25 hits. This is only for the "identifier" as seen above.

```
    for tr in soup.find_all('tr'):
        for td in tr.find_all('td'):
            for span in td.find_all('span', {"class": "aClass"}):
                if span.parent.name == 'a':
                    print span.text
```

Okay -- my bad. This was a parser problem, and I was impatient when trying the different ones. alecxce already suggested this. Problem fixed.

Comment: Could you share your complete code? Thanks.

Comment: See complete code above

Comment: Is putting a `time.sleep(5000)` after the `submit()` making any difference?

Comment: Also, what if you play around with the parsers: `soup = BeautifulSoup(pagehtml, "lxml")` or `soup = BeautifulSoup(pagehtml, "html.parser")` or `soup = BeautifulSoup(pagehtml, "html5lib")`?

Comment: the lxml parser is the only one that doesn't freeze. Provides same result with the 2nd loop suggested above, 1450 for 951 items. If I do the original code I still only get 25 items. That said - neither time.sleep nor parser makes any difference

Comment: I've been messing around with different iterations for a while now, and I feel fairly certain I'm doing something wrong with that. #noob

Comment: @alecxe is it normal for parsers to not fully function with broken html? I still wont be able to fetch all my results (951 expected, getting 633) but I'm guessing this is the best I can get?

Comment: Difficult to tell, can you share the URL of the page you are scraping? Thanks.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/103907/discussion-between-alecxe-and-user3471881).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is a complete code with several improvements (getting the desired 319 rows in the `data` list):

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.select import Select
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC


searches = ['Norway']
data = [['ID', 'MESSAGE']]

driver = webdriver.PhantomJS()
wait = WebDriverWait(driver, 10)
url = 'your URL here'
driver.get(url)

for search in searches:
    # select 1000 results
    select = Select(driver.find_element_by_id("count"))
    select.select_by_visible_text("1000")

    # provide the search query and search
    input = driver.find_element_by_id("q")
    input.clear()
    input.send_keys(search)
    input.submit()

    # wait until loaded
    wait.until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.CSS_SELECTOR, "a.top")))

    # parse search results with BeautifulSoup
    pagehtml = driver.page_source
    soup = BeautifulSoup(pagehtml, "html5lib")
    identifiers = [id.get_text(strip=True)
                   for id in soup.find_all('span', {"class": "glyphicon glyphicon-open-file"})]
    messages = [message.get_text(strip=True)
                for message in soup.find_all('td', {"colspan": "3"})]
    data.extend(zip(identifiers, messages))

print(len(data))
```